# Memory leak issue in axwmplib playlist

Tags: c#, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am playing a playlist using axwmplib where I'd Set mode "loop" as true. With every change in media of playlist the size of memory consumption by application get increases continuously. I have to play this playlist 24*7 and this result in system failure.

Comment: then report it to the makers.. whats your question?